# SwiftUI animation: Some implicit transition animations broken on iOS 13?

Tags: animation, swiftui

Tested on Xcode 11.3.1 and 11.4:

When attaching implicit animations to a transition, some transition types appear to be broken. Specifically, any position-related transitions do not apply the given implicit animation. `.slide`, `.move`, `.offset` are broken. `.opacity` and `.scale` seem ok. (See attachment)

Explicit animations seem to work fine in all cases.

Even with custom compound Transitions, the position-related sub-transitions do not respond to implicit animation.

**Is this a bug, or expected behavior?**

Seems like this would be a problem if you want to trigger multiple different animation curves for specific UI elements based on an implicit property change.

[image]

```
struct MyExample: View {

    @State private var isShowing = true

    private let myAnimation = Animation.spring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.2, blendDuration: 3.0)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:20) {
            if self.isShowing {
                Text("Opacity").modifier(MyBigFont())
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(myAnimation))

                Text("Scale").modifier(MyBigFont())
                    .transition(AnyTransition.scale.animation(myAnimation))

                Text("Slide").modifier(MyBigFont())
                    .transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(myAnimation))

                Text("Move").modifier(MyBigFont())
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing).animation(myAnimation))

                Text("Offset").modifier(MyBigFont())
                    .transition(AnyTransition.offset(x: 20, y: 0).animation(myAnimation))

                Text("Custom").modifier(MyBigFont())
                    .transition(AnyTransition.myCustomTransition.animation(myAnimation))
            }

            Spacer()

            Button(action: {
                self.isShowing.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Implicit Toggle")
            }

            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(self.myAnimation) {
                    self.isShowing.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Explicit Toggle")
            }
        }
    }

}

struct MyBigFont: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.purple)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .font(Font.system(size: 21).bold())
    }
}

struct MyCustomTransition: ViewModifier {

    var isEnabled: Bool

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        if isEnabled {
            return content
                .offset(x: 20.0, y: 0.0)
                .opacity(0)
        } else {
            return content
                .offset(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
                .opacity(1)
        }

    }
}

extension AnyTransition {
    static let myCustomTransition = AnyTransition.modifier(
        active: MyCustomTransition(isEnabled: true),
        identity: MyCustomTransition(isEnabled: false))
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            MyExample()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Javier, implicit animations on transitions no longer work as of Xcode 11.2

If anyone has newer information, please reply.

> Note that since XCode 11.2, transitions no longer work with implicit animations.

https://swiftui-lab.com/advanced-transitions/

Answer (score 5):

To have implicit transitions animatable correctly it needs to make animatable container that includes these transitions.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

Here is the only fix made:

```swift
struct MyExample: View {

    @State private var isShowing = true

    private let myAnimation = Animation.spring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.2, blendDuration: 3.0)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:20) {
            if self.isShowing {

                ...      // all your code here

            }
        }.animation(myAnimation)    // << fix !!
    }
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't trigger the implicit animations attached to each transition. It overrides them all with an explicit animation. This is the same effect as wrapping the property change with a single `withAnimation {}`

Answer (score -1):

Asperi's answer is totally right, just tested it with Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.2 / macOS 12.2 with the following simple example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            roundedRect(color: .blue)
            if show {
                roundedRect(color: .red)
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut))
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(show ? "Hide" : "Show") {
                show.toggle()
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 190, height: 420, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

Suprisingly, this worked:

[Opacity transition with implicit animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzFm6.gif)

Then I tried the same setup, just with the `.slide` transition, and then it stopped working:

[Slide transition with implicit animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2NXI.gif)

Then I tried moving the animation out to the next container (VStack) like Asperi suggested above:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            roundedRect(color: .blue)
            if show {
                roundedRect(color: .red)
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(show ? "Hide" : "Show") {
                show.toggle()
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 190, height: 420, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

Lo and behold, the transition started animating again.

[Slide transition with implicit animation on the containing VStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBONq.gif)

Comment: Yeah this is a workaround for animating a single view. But look at my comment on Asperi's answer. It doesn't solve the problem when you have multiple subviews that each want their own different implicit animation. (Like my original example)

Comment: No it's not. In your original question, you are using the same animation for every view (.animation(myAnimation)), just different transitions. So if you keep the transition on the Text, but move the .animation(myAnimation) on the containing VStack, it should work.

Comment: My question was about triggering different implicit transitions and animation per element. No workaround for that as far as I know. The link in the accepted answer still seems to be right (Implicit transitions don't work).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31038500)